# How to solve runtime error "No entry could be found" during Tycho?

Tags: tycho

I have an Eclipse plug-in test that wants to access the resources in another plug-in's `resources` source folder. However, when I build them with Tycho, the test fails with:

`No entry could be found or if the caller does not have the appropriate AdminPermission[this,RESOURCE] and the Java Runtime Environment supports permissions.`

What could the problem be?

Comment: "No entry could be found" isn't something that rings a bell. Maybe you also share the code you used to load the resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `resources` source folder is missing from the `bin.includes` section of its `build.properties`, add it.

Comment: You can accept your own answer if it solved the problem for you. Then it would be clear that you are not looking for other answers.